# How to recognize content type of uploaded file? How to prevent possible xss attacks via it?

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, xss, content-type, apache-tika

This is more of a theoretical question:
I would like to know if there's a way in spring boot to recognize the content type of an uploaded file precisely (with 100% accuracy).

I saw many answers for similar questions suggest apache tika; but as far as I understand, it guesses the type bases only on the first few "magic" bytes.

That evoked my curiosity about content such as. e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
</root>
// some ugly javascript
makeAmericaGreatAgain();
```

My questions are these:

- will tika be happy with just the XML header (the "magic" bytes...?) and ignore the rest of the file?
- if the backend returns such a file with XML content type headers to a browser, will the browser display it and run the javascript? So, will this basically lead to a successful XSS attack?
- If so, what is the best way to prevent the attack? Is it possible to tell a browser to not run javascript for a given "content"? Something like:

> anyData = fetch(GET, "/anything/json-or-file-or-whatever-stream-of-data")
>
> {{ anyData }}

Are the double brackets meant to be used only for text?
If so, is there an universal way to handle other content types such as images, texts from rich text editors, XMLs, audio files, embedded content,...?

Comment: So I read https://medium.com/@d.harish008/what-is-a-magic-byte-and-how-to-exploit-1e286da1c198, and it's actually possible. The guy even uploaded a PHP code with a parameter; and when he accessed it via URL, he was able to send in any command he wanted. That's pretty insane.

Answer (score 0):

My findings and assumption (so far) are the following:

- browsers have multiple parsers which they use to process (and e.g. display) different types of content
- browsers decide which parser to use based on the content type header returned in response
- parsers are e.g. for HTML, XML, javascript, images,...
- parsers for e.g. HTML, XML, javascript, etc...may run into the `script` tag (or similar) and run the code inside, which may be dangerous
- parsers for e.g. images (content type `image/*`) don't interpret the content as javascript and so don't run it - so they are probably safe against XSS.
- magic bytes are bytes at the beginning of the file. They aren't displayed, but they are used to identify the content of the file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) - e.g. png file is recognized by starting with `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A`

So, my current understanding is that the following is safe against XSS:

1. check the uploaded bytes with apache tika (magic bytes) - do not care about what the file really contains, it will be handled by parsers in the browser - meaning it's safe to trust e.g. image files, but not e.g. XML files (**I am not really sure about this**)
2. when returning the content back to a browser, add content type header, so it's parsed as a desired type, and not e.g. as javascript, so any code inside is not run
3. browser will use the appropriate parser, try to display the content, and if it fails (possibly because of some weird hacky content), it will not display anything (or maybe the [image]) icon